# how is code for sending parameters to the JSON type URL?

Tags: iphone, ios5

hi all i am getting response like below URL but i have to pass NSString type parameters to the   My required URL as like shown below how is  code for sending request to the URL in iPhone? so plz give me any one for my request.

## define kLatestKivaLoansURL [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://eventappmobiledev.cloudapp.net/EventDataService.svc/GetTechnologies?APIKey=62CB769C-E17E-484E-BE51-C144D062D076"]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check ASIHTTPRequest for all types of requests